# Datetime fields in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use the following code:

```
= f.datetime_field :start_time
```

But my field looks like a commond text field, without date and time pickers. How can I fix it?  My layout uses HTML5 for Doctype. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="datetime">` is only supported in opera and partly -webkit browsers - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input) and [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/input-datetime).

Use some datepicker plugin, like JQuery UI [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Or [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).